# What is the lshw equivalent in windows which can give me a tree structure of hardware as lshw does on Linux?

Tags: windows, list, hardware, pci

I need hardware information just as listed below which was generated using lshw in linux. I need a windows equivalent without a GUI more preferably like a code or dll which can be used to extract the information in the same tree like structure. Please note Wmi is not a suitable option as it does not give me empty slots while lshw does.

---

```
test-pc3
    description: Desktop Computer
    version: System Version
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 smp-1.4 smp
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop cpus=2 family=To Be Filled By O.E.M. sku=To Be Filled By O.E.M. uuid=C0EFA9AB-8DFE-D511-9075-BCAEC5B65DA4
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: M4N68T-M-LE-V2
       vendor: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev X.0x
       serial: MT700CK35903797
       slot: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 0402
          date: 07/30/2010
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 960KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 250 Processor
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 15.6.3
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: AM3
          size: 3GHz
          capacity: 3GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 200MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
     *-memory:0
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 2a
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: PartNum0
             vendor: Manufacturer0
             physical id: 0
             serial: SerNum0
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: PartNum1
             vendor: Manufacturer1
             physical id: 1
             serial: SerNum1
             slot: DIMM1
     *-cpu:1
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@1
          version: 15.6.3
          size: 3GHz
          capacity: 3GHz
          capabilities: cpufreq
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 0
             size: 128KiB
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 1
             size: 1MiB
     *-memory:1 UNCLAIMED
          description: RAM memory
          product: MCP61 LPC Bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: a
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: a1
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
          capabilities: ht bus_master cap_list
          configuration: latency=0
     *-isa
          description: ISA bridge
          product: MCP61 LPC Bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: isa bus_master
          configuration: latency=0
          resources: ioport:900(size=256)
     *-serial
          description: SMBus
          product: MCP61 SMBus
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 1.1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pm cap_list
          configuration: driver=nForce2_smbus latency=0
          resources: irq:10 ioport:e00(size=64) ioport:600(size=64) ioport:700(size=64)
     *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
          description: RAM memory
          product: MCP61 Memory Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 1.2
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.2
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
          configuration: latency=0
     *-usb:0
          description: USB Controller
          product: MCP61 USB Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 2
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
          version: a3
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:20 memory:dfefb000-dfefbfff
     *-usb:1
          description: USB Controller
          product: MCP61 USB Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 2.1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
          version: a3
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: debug pm ehci bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:21 memory:dfefac00-dfefacff
     *-pci:0
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
          version: a1
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pci ht subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
          resources: ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:dff00000-dfffffff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
             vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:01:06.0
             logical name: eth1
             version: 10
             serial: 00:21:27:c6:00:27
             size: 100Mbit/s
             capacity: 100Mbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.5 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
             resources: irq:19 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:dffffc00-dffffcff memory:dffc0000-dffdffff
     *-multimedia
          description: Audio device
          product: MCP61 High Definition Audio
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 5
          bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pm msi ht bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0 maxlatency=5 mingnt=2
          resources: irq:22 memory:dfef4000-dfef7fff
     *-ide:0
          description: IDE interface
          product: MCP61 IDE
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 6
          bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pata_amd latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:0 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:ffa0(size=16)
     *-bridge
          description: Ethernet interface
          product: MCP61 Ethernet
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 7
          bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
          logical name: eth0
          version: a2
          serial: bc:ae:c5:b6:5d:a4
          size: 100000000
          capacity: 1000000000
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: bridge pm msi ht bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full ip=10.0.0.53 latency=0 link=yes maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
          resources: irq:43 memory:dfef9000-dfef9fff ioport:d480(size=8)
     *-ide:1
          description: IDE interface
          product: MCP61 SATA Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 8
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
          logical name: scsi3
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ide pm msi ht bus_master cap_list emulated
          configuration: driver=sata_nv latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:23 ioport:d400(size=8) ioport:d080(size=4) ioport:d000(size=8) ioport:cc00(size=4) ioport:c880(size=16) memory:dfef8000-dfef8fff
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST3250312AS
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: JC45
             serial: 5VMVP3ER
             size: 232GiB (250GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00065eee
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: b09b2d81-893c-4078-a0f5-ed3f095feb6a
                size: 74GiB
                capacity: 74GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2011-05-13 20:23:38 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2011-10-02 22:38:18 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2011-10-09 16:06:10 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 2860MiB
                capacity: 2860MiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   capacity: 2860MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSWIN4.1
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                logical name: /windows
                version: FAT32
                serial: 874c-2af5
                size: 37GiB
                capacity: 37GiB
                capabilities: primary fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,gid=46,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSWIN4.1
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                logical name: /dos
                version: FAT32
                serial: 7144-97bc
                size: 118GiB
                capacity: 118GiB
                capabilities: primary fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,gid=46,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
     *-ide:2
          description: IDE interface
          product: MCP61 SATA Controller
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 8.1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
          logical name: scsi5
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ide pm msi ht bus_master cap_list emulated
          configuration: driver=sata_nv latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:22 ioport:c800(size=8) ioport:c480(size=4) ioport:c400(size=8) ioport:c080(size=4) ioport:c000(size=16) memory:dfeef000-dfeeffff
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GH22NS50
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/scd0
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: TN03
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
     *-pci:1
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: 9
          bus info: pci@0000:00:09.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:40
     *-pci:2
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: b
          bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:41
     *-pci:3
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: c
          bus info: pci@0000:00:0c.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:42
     *-display
          description: VGA compatible controller
          product: C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a]
          vendor: nVidia Corporation
          physical id: d
          bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
          version: a2
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
          configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
          resources: irq:21 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:dfec0000-dfedffff
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Address Map
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Link Control
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-scsi
          physical id: e
          bus info: usb@1:7
          logical name: scsi26
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@26:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
```

---

Comment: You may be able to obtain this information via SetupDiGetClassDevs() and friends, but it will be a chore.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at Microsoft's `DevCon`: [The DevCon command-line utility functions as an alternative to Device Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272).

The source code for `DevCon` is also available in the Windows DDK (which is available from http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/ddk/default.mspx) under DDK `root\Src\Setup\Devcon`, along with documentation. The source code shows you how to use the various API in the [SetupAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I know that `USBDeview` is like `lsusb` on Windows. You can find it from http://www.nirsoft.net/ .

Perhaps one of Nirsoft's other software is helpful for your needs? Like `Devmanview` or `Driverview`?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the tree view, then go into Device Manager (usually in System->Hardware). This will show you all the devices in your system. It's better than the command prompt in Ubuntu, although you might have to dig further than normal to find specifics like data width or channel modes.

An easier option is to go to [the Piriform website](http://piriform.com/), and pick up Speccy. I'd suggest the portable build, because it's more convenient, and besides, you'll only use it a few times.

Speccy is a real cool program that will detect almost anything you want to know. I've never had any inaccuracies, and this is my go-to tool for new hardware.

Comment: I just used Speccy for the first time. On an Acer TravelMate 5742. It does not even list ethernet or wlan devices, though present. For both of these, I also could not extract any useful information from Device Manager, not even manufacturer. Instead I ran an Ubuntu Live cd and ran lshw from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, please see [my answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/54901/40193) at SR SE.

- **[DevCon.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-examples)** (**CLI**) which is available in sources from the [github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/setup/devcon), or alternatively can be obtained from the Windows SDK, WDK (Windows Driver Kit) or EDWK.
- **[USBview.exe](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview)** (**GUI**) - available in same location as above. And described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/usbview).
- **[listdevs.exe](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/tree/master/examples)** (**CLI**) -  You can use some of the [libusb](https://libusb.info/) based tools found in their [github](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases).

Some Example usages:

```sh
# Some useful devcon examples:
#devcon.exe classes             # to list all available classes
#devcon.exe listclass net
#devcon.exe hwids =net
#devcon.exe driverfiles "HID\Vid_045e&Pid_0039&Rev_0121"
#devcon.exe find "*usb*"
#devcon.exe find "=libusb-win32 devices"
#devcon.exe hwids USB\*

# devcon.exe listclass usb

Listing 11 devices in setup class "USB" (Universal Serial Bus controllers).
USB\VID_0BDA&PID_0139\20100201396000000                     : Realtek USB 2.0 Card Reader
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&29650814&0                                 : USB Root Hub
USB\VID_8087&PID_8008\5&55A390B&0&1                         : Generic USB Hub
...
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_8C2D&SUBSYS_11CD1043&REV_05\3&11583659&0&D0:  
Intel(R) 8 Series/C220 Series USB EHCI #2 - 8C2D

# devcon.exe hwids USB\*

USB\VID_0BDA&PID_0139\20100201396000000
    Name: Realtek USB 2.0 Card Reader
    Hardware IDs:
        USB\VID_0BDA&PID_0139&REV_3960
        USB\VID_0BDA&PID_0139
    Compatible IDs:
        USB\Class_FF&SubClass_06&Prot_50
        USB\Class_FF&SubClass_06
        USB\Class_FF
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&29650814&0
    Name: USB Root Hub
    Hardware IDs:
        USB\ROOT_HUB20&VID8086&PID8C26&REV0005
        USB\ROOT_HUB20&VID8086&PID8C26
        USB\ROOT_HUB20
...
```

The libusb tools:

```sh
# listdevs.exe

0bda:0139 (bus 2, device 1) path: 8
8086:8c26 (bus 3, device 0)
8087:8008 (bus 1, device 1) path: 1
13d3:3402 (bus 2, device 3) path: 5
16c0:05df (bus 2, device 14) path: 2

# Then use xusb to get details of the VID/PID:
# xusb.exe -i 16c0:05df

Using libusb v1.0.22.11312
Opening device 16C0:05DF...
Device properties:
        bus number: 2
         port path: 2 (from root hub)
             speed: 1.5 Mbit/s (USB LowSpeed)

Reading device descriptor:
            length: 18
      device class: 0
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 16C0:05DF
         bcdDevice: 0100
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

Reading BOS descriptor: no descriptor

Reading first configuration descriptor:
             nb interfaces: 1
              interface[0]: id = 0
interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 03.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0008
          polling interval: 0A

Claiming interface 0...

Reading string descriptors:
   String (0x01): "digistump.com"
   String (0x02): "DigiUSB"

Releasing interface 0...
Closing device...
libusb: error [parse_bos] unexpected descriptor 0 (expected f)
```